# Why do I get an error that says "reached end of file while parsing"?

Tags: java

Okay so I made a simple thing in Java. 
Here it is.

```
class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {

      // Scanner initialization
      Scanner myInfo = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Who are you? ");
      String inputName = myInfo.nextLine();

      System.out.println("How old are you? ");
      int inputAge = myInfo.nextInt();

      System.out.println("What is your aim? ");
      String inputAim = myInfo.next();

      System.out.println("My name is " +inputName+ "I am " +inputAge+ "years old. I wanna be a " +inputAim);
```

When I try to run it, it gives me an error that says "reached end of file while parsing".

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the tag(s) you included. You are asking an off-topic question. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @DavidPostill please don't migrate typo questions to Stack Overflow. They are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) there.

Answer (score 1):

I know little about Java but you have two `{` characters and no `}`. I blindly bet this is the culprit. End of file is unexpected until all opening brackets meet their closing counterparts.